# How to update the VS Running Document Table from Task Run method group

Tags: c#, visual-studio, async-await, task-parallel-library, visual-studio-extensions

I am trying to rename the RDT document outside of the UI thread and getting the below exception

```
System.AccessViolationException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
```

Here is the sample of the code

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool> Save(DocDataSaveArgs args)
{
   // Some other code
   
   await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
   {
      OnSave(eventArgs);
   });
   
   // Some other code
}

protected virtual void OnSave(DocDataSaveEventArgs eventArgs)
{
   // Begin Save Data

   // End Save Data
   
   object o;
   int hr = VsWinFrame.GetProperty((int)__VSFPROPID.VSFPROPID_pszMkDocument, out o);
   SVCDbg.Assert(hr == EXTCom.S_OK);

   IVsRunningDocumentTable runningDocTable = UILGlobal.VSGPkg.ServiceProvider.GetIVsRunningDocumentTable();
   hr = runningDocTable.RenameDocument((string)o, UIVDocView.UILDocData.VSGDocData.Path, Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSConstants.HIERARCHY_DONTCHANGE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSConstants.VSITEMID_NIL);
   SVCDbg.Assert(hr == EXTCom.S_OK);
}
```

What should be the correct way to update the RDT from a threadpool worker thread?

Comment: You can't modify the UI thread from another thread in any operating system, any application. Period. You'll have to return/marshal the data you want back to the UI thread and modify the UI there. If `Save` runs on the background thread, any UI modifications should happen after the `await Task.Run` call. If the modifications need data from that method, the method should return a `Task<ThatData>` with a type containing the necessary data

Comment: Any answers that show using `Invoke`, `InvokeAsync` or dispatchers do the exact same thing in a more convoluted way. These were used before `async/await` was introduced in 2012, to make a delegate run on the UI thread. The resulting code was quite a bit more convoluted

Comment: Another possibility is to create a `Progress<T>` class in code that runs on the UI thread and call `Report` as needed from a background thread. The delegate/event passed to `Progress` will run on the UI thread using the data passed to `Report`